# Need to total record counts in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to get a sum of total records partitioned by entity and status.  I'm able to do this by creating several queries, but I'd like to know if there's a simpler way than my method.

This is the data:

```
    EntityID   StatusDate   StatusType   Total
      10        2017-07-19      H1         3
      10        2017-08-18      H1         3
      10        2017-09-01      H1         3
      10        2017-04-01      H4         23
      10        2017-04-01      H4         23
```

In this example StatusType = H1 has 3 different records, for a total of 3 with that status.  StatusType = H4 has 23 different records, for a total of 23(I didn't include all 23 lines for obvious reasons).  I'd like to total this column to display 26, which is the total of the 3 H1 status and 23 H4 statuses.

This is what I came up with:

```
    Select a.*
    into #test
    from
    (select t.*, row_number()over(partition by entityid, statustypename, total order by statusdate) as rn
    from Table t) a
    where rn = 1
```

This produced the following:

```
    EntityID    StatusDate   StatusType   Total   rn
      10         2017-07-19     H1          3      1
      10         2017-04-01     H5          23     1
```

I then created this:

```
    Select a.*,
    sum(total) over(partition by entityid order by statusdate)as newtotal
    from #test
```

Which produced:

```
    EntityID    StatusDate    StatusType   Total   NewTotal
      10         2017-04-01     H4          23        23
      10         2017-07-19     H1           3        26
```

The problem with this is it's getting kind of messy creating all these queries, plus I lost all my detail data from the original data set.  Is there a more efficient way to get these totals?

Comment: What do you want your result set to look like? Do you want the count of H1 (3), the count of H4 (23) and the total (26)?

Comment: I'd like to see the count of H1(3), H4(23) and total (26).

Comment: is this solved?

Comment: No, the answer didn't really work.  I ended up creating several queries to get the answer.  I was hoping for something more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

You can group by the entity and status, and then use `COUNT()` to get the total of each status, then union that result with a total count, like this:

```
SELECT StatusType, COUNT(*) 
FROM Table
GROUP BY EntityID, StatusType

UNION

SELECT StatusType = 'Total', COUNT(*)
FROM Table
```